# Fixed precision in C

Tags: c, precision

Can C language handle user-set precision calculations? I know that **float** and **double** type won't do the job, nor do exist some fixed-precision variable types, like I've seen in *Java* or in *C#*.

I'm asking so because I'm writing a program that implements an algorithm which calculates an approximation of *y=log x*, which needs to do fixed-precision arithmetic both to terminate and to give a correct approximation of the logarithm. My program terminates, since **float** has however a maximum precision, but the answer contains more error than when I try the algorithm with pencil and paper.

For instance, once x has been specified, the program first does this declaration:

```
float z = floor(x*pow(a, p-1) + offset)/pow(a,p);
```

where a is an integer, for example 10, and p is another integer, the precision number, for example 3. I discovered with GDB that, if we assume that x=4, z is not 0.4, as it should be, but it's actually 0.400000006

I know that this is the normal behaviour of floats and doubles, but in this specific program I need to specify the exact number of digits after the radix point, that is p, as written above. In fact, when the program terminates, the logarithm of x is calculated with the intrinsic error of the algorithm, plus the error given by floating-point arithmetic every time there is a calculation similar to the one above.

So, is there a way I can manually set the precision of the variables so as to improve the accuracy of the final result?

Comment: You can do your calculations with any types you want, but there are no library functions for fixed precision arithmetic in the standard library. Also, binary floating-point numbers stay binary floating-point numbers, `.4` cannot be exactly represented in it.

Comment: Bear in mind that (standard) floating point works in terms of binary digits of precision. This doesn't map cleanly onto decimal digits, which is what you're looking at.

Comment: I believe the `gmp` library exists for this purpose, but I'm a bit unclear on the math angles and may be misunderstanding your question.

Comment: When float fails, you can always try bigger floats. You can go up to long double (usually that's 80 bits) in standard C before you need to use third party libraries.

Comment: "since float has however a maximum precision".  _All_ data types have a maximum precision be it 4, 7, 19, million or google.  What is the range of precision you seek?  BTW: `0.400000006`, rounded to the typical decimal precision of a `float`, is `0.4`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend [`GNU MPFR`](http://www.mpfr.org/) library for precise floating-point computation. [`GMP`](https://gmplib.org/) is very robust and specialized in large integers (`mpz`, `mpq` or internal `mpn` categories), however they recommed this library for multi-precision floating-point, even directly on their main site:

> New projects should strongly consider using the much more complete GMP
>   extension library mpfr instead of mpf.

Answer (score 1):

If you are aiming for high precision numbers, I recommend the use of GNU MP library.
Gnu multiple precision library allows you to manually set the precision of your numbers, raging from fairly low values up to huge, thousand digit numbers.

Here is the link.
https://gmplib.org/

I hope I have helped.

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely need to use an [Arbitrary Precision Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Libraries) to avoid the precision errors with native floats/doubles.  That Wikipedia page lists three separate C libraries that support floats.